# Deploying Rails github with a SharedServer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, dreamhost

I am trying to deploy a Rails application online. My host right now is dream host. Although i am not to sure how to deploy my apps. At the moment i am on a shared server, but i am considering upgrading to a VPS, but the questions remains! Do i need Git hub or not. If i need to have git hub to make it private do i have to pay or an alternative exist.

What I meant by not to sure on how to deploy rails is that I have a localhost provided with webrick and with database.yml settup otherwise everything else is dark for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use capistrano to deploy you application to shared host or VPS via SSH.

https://help.github.com/articles/deploying-with-capistrano.